# Differences between emulator's SD Card and real phone's SD Card

Tags: file-io, android-emulator, android-sdcard

My target is to read a file in SD Card  and then process it in my program.

All THINGS WORKS FINE IN ANDROID EMULATOR!!!!

Unfortunately, when I work on my smartphone it didn't work at all!

```
     public void receiveVideoRawData() throws IOException{
      byte[] buf_rcv = new byte[153600];
      File file = new File("/mnt/sdcard/Bluetooth/ardrone.raw");
      ByteArrayOutputStream ous = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
      InputStream ios = new FileInputStream(file);
      int read = 0;
      while ( (read = ios.read(buf_rcv)) != -1 ) {
                ous.write(buf_rcv, 0, read);
             }
                ous.close();
                ios.close();

    ReadRawFileImage readMyRawData=new ReadRawFileImage();
    image = readMyRawData.readUINT_RGBImage(buf_rcv);
        File outputfile = new File("/mnt/sdcard/Bluetooth/ardroneCVT1.jpg");
        OutputStream _outStream  = new FileOutputStream(outputfile);
        Bitmap pBitmap = image ;
        pBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, _outStream);       
          _outStream.flush();
          _outStream.close();       

}
```

}

Comment: When asking question, don't just say "it didn't work" and dump a bunch of code, you should specify what you're expecting to happen, what deviates from your expectation (dud the file get created, did the write succeeds, but with an error, etc), and what error message you get or don't get (what's in logcat, did you get a crash, etc).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not supposed to hardcode the path to external storage directly because this may differ between devices, instead use getExternalStorageDirectory():

```
File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                      .getAbsolutePath(), filename);
```